# Django rest framework 3.10.3 is not running exception handler

Tags: error-handling, django-rest-framework

I am trying my first django rest framework app, I am using djangorestframework==3.10.3

I created a simple project:

```
./mysite
./mysite/__init__.py
./mysite/settings.py
./mysite/urls.py
./mysite/wsgi.py
./db.sqlite3
./polls
./polls/migrations
./polls/migrations/__init__.py
./polls/models.py
./polls/__init__.py
./polls/apps.py
./polls/admin.py
./polls/exceptions.py
./polls/tests.py
./polls/urls.py
./polls/views.py
./manage.py
```

I have one view in the polls application which only throws a ParseError which is an ApiException (according to the documentation it is handled by custom exception https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling)

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.exceptions import ParseError

# Create your views here.
@csrf_exempt
def test_view(request):
    raise ParseError("test!", 409)
```

Here is my custom exception, which is at polls/exceptions.py

from rest_framework.views import exception_handler

```
def base_exception_handler(exc, context):
    print('DEBUUUUUUUUUG!!!!!!!')
    return JsonResponse({"message": "base exception", "status": 404}, status=404)
```

And finally the mysite/settings.py - registering the custom exception handler (all the rest of the file is default):

```
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'rest_framework',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
...
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'polls.exceptions.base_exception_handler',
}
```

when running the server and navigating to the view which is defined at http://localhost:8000/test I get:

1. if I set debug to True - I get exception page with the exception I raised
2. if I set debug to False - I get an HTML page with **Server Error (500)**

I tried to check whether default exception handler is executed by setting a breakpoint at rest_framework.views.exception_handler (I didn't change any setting for it so it should use default as described in the documentation), however it is not called. I get an HTML page in response.

Here are the packages I am using (requirements.txt):

```
Django==2.2.7
djangorestframework==3.10.3
pytz==2019.3
sqlparse==0.3.0
```

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is facing the same problem, here is the solution. The problem is that function view is missing the @api_view() decorator, this fixes the problem:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.exceptions import ParseError
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

# Create your views here.
@csrf_exempt
@api_view()
def test_view(request):
        raise ParseError("test!", 409)
```

It would have been great if the documentation be more detailed about it.